# How to specify text segmentation in R?

Tags: r, nlp

I am trying to separate my text into two meaningful words. It separates the words but it also separates two character words like "is","it",etc.

Is there a way to specify or set the function so that it will ignore these two character words when text segmenting?

```
    wl <- read.table("http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/wordlist")$V1

    > check.word <- function(x, wl) {
    +   x <- tolower(x)
    +   nc <- nchar(x)
    +   parts <- sapply(1:(nc-1), function(y) c(substr(x, 1, y), 
    substr(x, y+1, nc)))
    +   parts[,parts[1,] %in% wl & parts[2,] %in% wl] 
    + }
    > check.word("isgood",wl)
    [1] "is"   "good"
    > check.word("is",wl)
    [1] "i" "s"
```

Comment: What's in `wl`? It's hard to know what is happening here without an idea of what the word list you're using is.

Comment: @Marius sorry I just added the wl

Comment: OK, part of the problem is that your word list does seem to contain an entry that is just `"s"`, so it's recognized as a valid word (same with `"i"`, but that's understandable). You could drop all 1-character entries (except "i" and "a"?) from the word list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove words shorter than 2 or 3 characters from you word database first

```
wl = wl[nchar(as.character(wl)) >= 3]
```